# Is there a facade for Unit Test Frameworks?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

You know, like SLF4J is to log4j, so X is to TestNG and jUnit?

Comment: Why, indeed?  The same question for logging - too many layers, too many choices.

Comment: So I won't have to couple of my codebase with the choice between the two. This makes switching frameworks easy.

Comment: One reason to use such an abstraction would be if you were writing a test extension that needed to be able to use different underlying test frameworks, e.g. a performance extension, or one that wrapped each test in a database transaction.

Answer (score 0):

What about Spring TestContext? According to documentation, it can provide what you are looking for.
I haven't used it in this way yet, so I may be wrong.

*The Spring TestContext  Framework (located in the org.springframework.test.context package) provides generic, annotation-driven unit and integration testing support that is agnostic of the testing framework in use, whether JUnit 3.8.2, JUnit 4.5+, TestNG 5.10, and so on.*

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#unit-testing

Comment: Looks like a candidate. I would want testimonies from people who used it though...